# Стоит ли использовать спецсимволы в названиях таблиц/столбцов?

Tags: mysql

В мануале MySQL.Ru указано, что можно называть таблицы и столбцы с применением различных символов (в более ранних версиях `_`, `$`). Стоит ли пользоваться или ограничиваться `_`?

Comment: Если у Вас есть выбор, то лучше огранчиться `_` - надежней.

Comment: Раз уж вы настаиваете на такой формулировке вопроса, то уточните, какие еще спец-символы вы имеете ввиду кроме `$` ?

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Legal_names.html

Comment: не стоит​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие вещи должны оговариваться в "стандарте кодирования" конкретной команды разработчиков. Что для одних норма, то другим кошмар. Важно чтобы в одном проекте не было разнообразия в этом плане.

В тех местах, где мне приходилось работать, для имен MySQL было принято ограничиваться нижним регистром латиницы + цифры и подчеркивание, snake-синтаксис.

Вот примеры толковых соглашений об именах:
http://anandarajpandey.com/2015/05/10/mysql-naming-coding-conventions-tips-on-mysql-database/
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/treffynnon/sqlstyle.guide/gh-pages/_includes/sqlstyle.guide.md

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать: нижний регистр, буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания.
Это наиболее часто встречающийся вариант в популярных FW.
Для сообщества PHP+MySQL, имхо, уже стандарт.
Чем меньше нестандартных решений, тем гибче и безопасней.